# pandas groupby at row and column level

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is in the  below format:

```
col1 col2 col3
A1    B1    t1
A2    B2    t2
A1    B1    t1
A1    B2    t2
```

I am grouping a dataframe as below:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].count()
```

which gives me the stats as:

```
A1 B1 2
A1 B2 1
A2 B2 1
```

What I would like the count be split on the basis of col3 like:

```
      t1   t2 
A1 B1 1    1
A1 B2 0    1
A2 B2 0    1
```

How could I achieve something like this?

Comment: So you have as many columns as the highest count? or should the first row be 2 0?

Comment: In the data only 2 values are possible for col3 - [t1 or t2], so I would like the count for the grouping of col1 and col2 be given as the total against t1 and t2 column values

Comment: Then I'd expect 2/0 for row 0 please check my answer and comment if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (df.assign(count=1)
         .pivot_table(index=['col1', 'col2'], columns='col3', values='count',
                      aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
      )
```

output:

```
col3       t1  t2
col1 col2        
A1   B1     2   0
     B2     0   1
A2   B2     0   1
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much, been struggling the whole day for this.

Answer (score 0):

### `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab([df['col1'], df['col2']], df['col3'])
```

---

```
col3       t1  t2
col1 col2        
A1   B1     2   0
     B2     0   1
A2   B2     0   1
```